# How to replace umlauts in an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, replace, pysimplegui

I'm trying to go through a bunch of html files and replace all the umlauts within with their according html-codes.
For some reason the output of the code shown below is the exactsame as the input and i don't know why.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pathlib


def ui_input():
    file_address = None
    layout = [[sg.Text("File: "), sg.InputText(key="-FILE_PATH-"), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=[("Html Files", ".*html")])],
              [sg.Submit('Convert'), sg.Cancel('Cancel')]
              ]
    window = sg.Window('Html Umlaut Converter', layout)

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Cancel':
        quit()
    elif event == 'Convert':
        file_address = values["-FILE_PATH-"]

    window.close()
    return file_address


def convert():
    duden = {"ä": "&auml;", "Ä": "&Auml;", "ö": "&ouml;", "Ö": "&Ouml;", "ü": "&uuml;", "Ü": "&Uuml;", "ß": "&szlig;"}
    file_address_pre = ui_input()
    fap = pathlib.Path(file_address_pre)
    file_address_post = fap.parent / (fap.stem + "_converted" + fap.suffix)

    for i in duden:
        print(i, duden[i])
        with open(file_address_pre, 'r') as prefile:
            predata = prefile.read()
            print("pre: ", predata)
            postdata = predata.replace(str(i), str(duden[i]))
            print("post: ", postdata)

        with open(file_address_post, "w") as postfile:
            postfile.write(postdata)


convert()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the output file for every letter in your dict. Running that code should replace occurences of ß in the original text, but no others. If you want to replace every special letter, try something like this instead:

```py
def convert():
    duden = {"ä": "&auml;", "Ä": "&Auml;", "ö": "&ouml;", "Ö": "&Ouml;", "ü": "&uuml;", "Ü": "&Uuml;", "ß": "&szlig;"}
    file_address_pre = ui_input()
    fap = pathlib.Path(file_address_pre)
    file_address_post = fap.parent / (fap.stem + "_converted" + fap.suffix)
    with open(file_address_pre, 'r') as prefile:
        predata = prefile.read()
    print("pre: ", predata)
    postdata = predata
    for i in duden:
        print(i, duden[i])
        postdata = postdata.replace(str(i), str(duden[i]))
        print("post: ", postdata)
    with open(file_address_post, "w") as postfile:
        postfile.write(postdata)
```

Comment: unfortunately this produces the same result. the output file is identical to the input.

Comment: I've tried it with other things than umlauts and html-codes and it works. for some reason however both umlauts as well as the html-codes seem to be problematic for .replace.

Comment: Have you double checked by e.g. deleting the `original_convert.html` page and making sure a new one is actually written?

I've tested on my end by pulling a random German Wikipedia article and replacing `ui_input()` with just a hardcoded path to it, seems to work.

Only other thing I can think of is, are you using Python 2 for some reason? It's possible the you're reading a byte string from the file instead of more abstract "text". In that case, your conversion won't work, as the byte string doesn't have the concept of unicode characters.

Comment: i have checked all that. for some reason i haven't found out until today .replace wouldn't replace my umlauts no matter if the input is through the ui, a command line argument or hardcoded into the script. i circumvented the issue by using .translate and forcing utf-8 encoding (although it should automatically be encoded in utf-8 and it still didn't work with .replace) instead.
i use the latest release of python so that can't be the problem either.

Comment: If you do `print(type(predata), type(postdata))` what's the output?